# numberOfRows issue WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, watchkit

i have a `WKInterfaceTable` with 3 prototype cells.

I append them by the cell tap, which first removes one latest cell and then fires `insertRowsAtIndexes` to insert two or more new cells.

For this to work properly i need to know the row count. The issue is - `tableView.numberOfRows` always gives me a result which is 3-4 rows (number grows the more cells i insert) greater than the actual table.

I'm wondering - does `FKInterfaceTable` save all the `row count` data, despite them being removed? or maybe this is some other bug or maybe my mistake?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I've just tested this and I always get the correct numbers of rows. Can you post the relevant parts of your code, there must be something wrong there.

Comment: @joern i was able to figure out the issue yet it grew into something different. i made a separate post for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371169